# Can Windows 7 cipher.exe securely wipe USB drive?

Tags: wipe, cipher

Using the command line tool cipher.exe built into Windows 7, can it be used to securely wipe a USB attached drive?

Comment: Try sdelete instead?  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897443

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but it may be slow compared to other tools that do the same job.

```
cipher /w:X:
```

Substitute the drive letter `X` for your flash drive. Don't forget the colon after the drive letter, or the command won't write to the drive.

Remember this only overwrites free space, so delete all files first.

Comment: Most free-space wipe tools I've seen, including `sdelete` and `cipher /w` work the same way: they create a really big file and fill it with random data (which they most likely obtain using `CryptGenRandom`). I don't see why would `cipher` be slower than others.

Comment: @ grawity, I did use the word "may"....http://www.somacon.com/p253.php

Comment: `cipher /w:X:` with double point at the end for drive X!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use sdelete from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897443

Answer (score 0):

Just commenting the answer given already (comments cannot be styled).

This is part of help printout for cipher.exe

```
Displays or alters the encryption of directories [files] on NTFS partitions.

  CIPHER /W:directory

   /W        Removes data from available unused disk space on the entire
              volume. If this option is chosen, all other options are ignored.
              The directory specified can be anywhere in a local volume. If it
              is a mount point or points to a directory in another volume, the
              data on that volume will be removed.
```

Is this true that only NTFS file system can be "cipher-ed"?

What about FAT32 format which is used lately for UEFI compatibility?

Seems better to use special utilities for wiping.

Comment: Works the same with FAT32.